# Modify Html Helpers in ASP.NET MVC3 with razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html-helper

i have the following Problem:

I want to know if it is possible to modify default html helper methods, e.g. the Html.BeginForm() method.

I know that i can write a custom helper method where i can add some stuff, but some of them have alot of overloaded functions.

then only thing i would need is, that you can add some custom html string "after" the element was rendered

e.g.:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("setDate", "DateController", new { DateId = Model.Date.Identifier }, FormMethod.Post, new { id = "setDateForm" })) {
    @* some input here... *@
}
```

and after the

```
<form></form>
```

i would like to render a validation script, or something else, lets say jQuery validator:

```
<script>$('#setDateForm').validate();</script>
```

since i dont want to do that over and over again (maybe i could forget it once..) it would be nice to modify the default Html helper.

If it is not possible i just might have to write my own BeginForm or a wrapper for the EndForm helper :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a very basic starting point, you could use something like this:

```
namespace YourProject.Helpers
{
    public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
    {
        public static IDisposable CustomBeginForm(this HtmlHelper helper, string html)
        {
            return new MvcFormExtension(helper, html);
        }

        private class MvcFormExtension : IDisposable
        {
            private HtmlHelper helper;
            private MvcForm form;
            private string html;

            public MvcFormExtension(HtmlHelper helper, string html)
            {
                this.helper = helper;
                this.form = this.helper.BeginForm();
                this.html = html;
            }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                form.EndForm();
                helper.ViewContext.Writer.Write(this.html);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You'd either need to add the namespace in your view or add it to the web.config file in your Views folder.  After that, you can use it like so:

```
@using (Html.CustomBeginForm("<p>test</p>")) {
    // Additional markup here
}
```

This works for me here but you'd certainly need to customise it to fit your needs, especially as you'll likely want to pass additional parameters to `Html.BeginForm()`.

Comment: Thank you, that helps alot. It is still sort of a wrapper but its alot better as my attempts :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to write your own Extension method do this. Get the code of the BeginForm method from Codeplex.(The MVC3 source code is [open source](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/) :) ) and make relevant updates to that to render the form like you want.

The code is available in the `FormExtensions.cs` class under the `System.Web.MVC` Project. Look for the FormHelper method which is being called from the BeginForm Overrides.

Comment: Thank you for the Info, i accepted John H's answer because he bothered to post an example but i did not think about that .NET itself could be open source, so it is also really helpful to browse the source there :)

Comment: No problem. Glad you could figure it out. John Deserves the +15 because he posted some code :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible. You'll have to do your own helpers.